# Calling infoWindow w/ Google Map V3 API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm not able to open an infoWindow when I select a polygon. Here's my code:

```
// Create Polygon
var polyline = new google.maps.Polygon({path:path, strokeColor: "#FF0000", strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 2, clickable:false});

// Place Polygon on Map
polyline.setMap(map);
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(35.910200,-84.085100));

// Create InfoWindow object
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: ' ',
suppressMapPan:true
});

// Create Click Event for Polygon
eventPolygonClick = google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', function() {

   // Load Content 
   infowindow.setContent("CLICKED me");
   // Open Window
   infowindow.open(map, polyline);

});
```

I would like to also pass the polygon and its respective content as variables to the eventPolygonClick. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use the latlng received from the click event to create a marker, and use that as the second parameter in the infowindow.open call.

```
eventPolygonClick = google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', function(event) { 
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng
   }); 

   infowindow.setContent("CLICKED me");
   infowindow.open(map, marker);

});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Re: Heitor's answer: A click event can be bound to the polyline and the event passed will be a point somewhere along the polyline.  No need to add a hidden marker. You can also use the polyline's content, but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Thank you, @javram. I'm still not having success. Can you browse my code at http://cspc.net/neighborhoods/neighborhoods2.html. I've implemented as you indicate above..but nothing happens when I click nor is an error posted.

Comment: Looks like you have the polyline set as clickable: false. try removing the clickable attribute completely from the polyline options, you should be good to go after that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have tried, a polygon cannot be used as an anchor for a InfoWindow. Try adding a marker somewhere inside or at the edge of the polygon, setVisible(false), and then infowindow.open(map, marker)

I didn't understand too clearly when you said pass the polygon. I believe you can use your variable 'polyline' freely, as for passing that with function(event), probably not. Have you tried either option?